# CakePHP database table for model was not found in datasource default

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am migrating a cakephp1.3 application in cakephp 2.x. Midway through development, I suddenly found myself with a "table not found" error.

In cakephp 1.3 lower case format for ,file name & also allow underscore between two words But as I have read documentation now only CAMEL format has allowed for naming convention.

I have a db file name **"case__studies"** previously we were using `models/case_study.php`

```
<?php

class Case_Study extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Case_Study';

var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');
var $belongsTo = array('User');


}

?>
```

but now according to new structure I have changed name of file `Model/CaseStudy.php`

and code for this file

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class CaseStudy extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'CaseStudy';

    var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');
    var $belongsTo = array('User');



}

?>
```

Comment: `var $` - you are still writing php4 style code - don't do that. `I have a db file` - do you mean a _model_ file, or that's the actual name of the table? Irrespective, the simplest way to ensure your model files are in the right place/have the right name is to re-bake them. I.e. move your model folder, and `cake bake model` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you cleared/disabled cache after any changes in the model layer.

You won't need that "name" property.

Comment: The cash was my problem .. Thanks .. :)